# select rows related with a column

Tags: mysql

I have table like this;

`col1    col2    col3    week
a       b       c       21
a       f       g       22
c       d       e       23
a       e       f       24
f       g       h       25
a       c       f       26
f       b       e       27`

I want to count rows those including 'a' with 1 week difference and 2 weeks and so on.For example; 
2 times with 1 week difference, 1 times with 0 difference.Like;

`week diff.   count
0               1
1               2
2               0`

an so on.
Thanks and i tried to be clear with my poor English.

Comment: can you please provide your expected output in table format

Comment: good. Let us know when you have done!

Comment: Please refer this link on how to frame your question, so that people can answer: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: @fa06
Thanks.I have edited my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the problem. But, supposing that:

- You want to count rows with 'a' in **any** column (col1, col2, col3).
- When you say "2 times with 1 week difference", it's 2 times because 'a' appears in 2 consecutive weeks: 21 and 22.
- Same way, there would be 3 rows (so, 3 times) with "2 week difference": rows with week column equal to 22, 24, 26

Then, the following query could be helpful:

```
SELECT 
    ABS(t2.week - t1.week) AS week_difference,
    COUNT(DISTINCT t1.week) AS count      
FROM 
    temp t1, temp t2
WHERE 
    ((t1.col1 = 'a' OR t1.col2 = 'a' OR t1.col3 = 'a') 
    AND (t2.col1 = 'a' OR t2.col2 = 'a' OR t2.col3 = 'a')) 
    AND  ABS(t2.week - t1.week) <= 2
GROUP BY 
    week_difference
ORDER BY 
    week_difference
```

Comment: Thanks, that is what i am trying to explain.But in your sql, what are t1,t2?Table names?I have only one table.

Comment: @Oaykol, "temp" would be your table. You can join a table to itself.

Comment: Thanks, that is what i am looking for but is it possible to count only week 21 and 22, 22 and 24, 24 and 26 not 21 and 24 or 22 and 26.So my desired output is; week diff.:1,count:1-week diff.:2,count:2

Comment: @Oaykol, you mean 2 weeks difference at the most, right? I've added an additional filter, so that the query will only return records less or equal to 2 weeks difference.

Comment: Not only 2 weeks but primary point is;only select week differences between 21-22, 22-24, 24-26, NOT between 21-24 or 21-26 or 22-26.